# CSS Transform Div with two background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of cards in a deck with a background-image with that of the deck, that when clicked, they do a flip animation and then change the background-image to the front-faced equivalent.

Each of these cards are a div.

My problem is, when the card is turned around after being clicked, the front-faced background image is also reversed. Any idea how I can solve this?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/667nxfze/

Here is my HTML of one card:

```
<div id='pack_cont' data-deckimage="url('/image/decks/deck1.png')">
    <div class='card init' data-image="url('/image/card/card1.png')"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript that reacts to it:

```
var card = $(this);
card.toggleClass('open');
setTimeout(function(){
    card.toggleClass('opened');
},300);
if(card.hasClass('open')){
    //Show that card image
    card.css('background-image', card.data('image'));
}else{
    //Show the Deck Image
    card.css('background-image', card.parent().data('deckimage'));
}
```

Here are the CSS classes:

```
.card{
 width: 147px;
 height: 280px;
 border-radius: 18px;
 position: absolute;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;

/*all transition to take 1s */
transition:all 1s;
-ms-transition:all 1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;


/*make card non selectable*/
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

/*while opening a card, again shift transform origin 
to vertical and horizontal center axis 
to give an actual flip effect
*/
.card.open{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card.opened{   
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use another timeout of 300 milliseconds for the transition effect, like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).parent().data('deckimage'));
  });
});

$('.card').click(function() {
  var card = $(this);
  card.toggleClass('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    card.toggleClass('opened');
  }, 300);
  if (card.hasClass('open')) {
    //Show that card image
    setTimeout (
     function() { 
            card.css('background-image', card.data('image')); }
    , 300)
  } else {
    //Show the Deck Image
    setTimeout (
          function() { card.css('background-image', card.parent().data('deckimage')); }
      , 300)
    
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 147px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /*all transition to take 1s */
  transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  /*make card non selectable*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/*while opening a card, again shift transform origin 
to vertical and horizontal center axis 
to give an actual flip effect
*/

.card.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg) scaleX(-1);;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg) scaleX(-1);;
}
}

.card.opened {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='pack_cont' data-deckimage="url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/eb/fb/03/ebfb03607fc73fa6a74de5ed3559b272--card-companies-card-deck.jpg')">
  <div class='card init' data-image="url('https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/vector-cards/screenshots/Jack_of_Spades.png')"></div>
</div>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Just updated my answer : the CSS transform property "scale" is what you wanted

Comment: Yeah, with the scale property it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) +1 then ?

Answer (score 4):

It is better to keep a flipper(container) with front and back face and flip it over on click.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card-container .front').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).parents('.card-container').data('deckimage'));
  });
  $('.card-container .back').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).parents('.card-container').data('image'));
  });
});

$('.card-container').click(function() {
  var card = $(this);
  card.toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.card-container {
 perspective: 1000px;
}
.card-container.open .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.card-container, .front, .back {
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-container" data-deckimage="url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/eb/fb/03/ebfb03607fc73fa6a74de5ed3559b272--card-companies-card-deck.jpg')" data-image="url('https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/vector-cards/screenshots/Jack_of_Spades.png')" >
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am suggesting that you use layers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<img1 src="/image/decks/deck1.png">
<img2 src="/image/decks/card1.png">


</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp